# Zero out array sent as parameter in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

How do you make all elements = 0 in the array sent as a parameter?

```
int myArrayFunction(int p_myArray[]) {
p_myArray[] = {0};//compiler error syntax error: ']'
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you can't. There's not enough information. You need to pass the length of the array too.

```
int myArrayFunction(int p_myArray[], int arrayLength) {
// --------------------------------------^ !!!
```

Then you can use [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/) or [`std::fill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/) to fill the array with zero. (`= {0}` only works in initialization.)

```
    std::fill(p_myArray, p_myArray+arrayLength, 0);
```

---

Alternatively, switch to use a `std::vector`, then you don't need to keep track of the length.

```
int myArrayFunction(std::vector<int>& p_myArray) {
    std::fill(p_myArray.begin(), p_myArray.end(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::fill_n()`. You'll need to pass the number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

With a loop. Which means you'll also need to give the array's size to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
int myArrayFunction(int p_myArray[], int size)
{
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
   {
      p_myArray[i] = 0;
   }
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::fill`. You need to pass the size of the array to the function somehow. Here's an example using the template size method, but you should consider passing a regular size parameter.

```
template<size_t size>
int myArrayFunction(int (&p_myArray)[size]) {
    std::fill(p_myArray, p_myArray + size, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That sort of assignment only works for the initialization of a new array,  not for modifying an existing array.

When you get an int[], you essentially have a pointer to some area in memory where the array resides. Making it point to something else (such as a literal array) won't be effective once you leave the function.

The most you can do is update individual cells with the [] operator or with library functions. For example, p_myArray[i]=0 (you can do this in a loop on i but you will need to pass the size to your function).

Answer (score 0):

If your p_myArray[] have a terminating character you can loop till that char is found.
For example if it were a string as a null-terminated char array you will stop when find '\0'

```
int myArrayFunction(char p_myArray[])
{

   for(int i=0;p_myArray[i]!='\0';i++)
       p_myArray[i]=0;

   //..
}
```

if p_myArray, have numbers from 0 to 100, you can use the 101 to indicate the array end, and so on..

So analize p_myArray use and content, if it can have a value that will never be used as data, you can use it as terminating code to flag the end.